# Error with jsonlite package in R

Tags: html, json, r, web, web-scraping

Has anyone ever received this error when trying to web scrape a site:

```
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) :
lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                     <!doctype html><html xmlns="htt
                   (right here) ------^
```

I do not understand why I am receiving this error when I scraped the first page of the site no problem with the same declaration on that first page. But the second page I get this error. Is there a way around this?

This works fine:

```
    jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.reddit.com/r/BestOfStreamingVideo/.json", flatten = TRUE)
```

Get the error here:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.reddit.com/r/BestOfStreamingVideo/?count=25&after=t3_5fvgls/.json", flatten = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter one does not return a JSON. It returns HTML. Enter both URL's in the browser and you'll see the difference.

I guess the URL you are looking for is:

https://www.reddit.com/r/BestOfStreamingVideo/.json?count=25&after=t3_5fvgls/

You need to put the `./json` first and append the URL parameter after.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you! :D